# Python: How can a typecast an object I obtain using Queue.get()

Tags: python, casting, queue

I have a multithreaded python program that passes messages objects (based on my own class called CommsMessage) between the threads using Queue.Queue.  The sending thread instantiated an instance of CommsMessage and put it on the queue.  The receiving thread dequeues a message like this:

`comms_rx = self.comms_rx_q.get(block=True, timeout=0.1)`

where `comms_rx_q` is an instance of Queue.Queue.  How can I specify that `comms_rx` is a CommsMessage object?

Comment: by specify do you just mean checking the type of queued items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: you can use type hints and aliases:

```
# could use NewType to create distinct type, CommsMsg
# maybe unnecessary (it'll be treated as a CommsMessage subclass)
CommsMsg = NewType('CommsMessage', CommsMessage)

# mark a type alias explicitly with TypeAlias declaration
# queue.Queue[CommsMessage] := all queue items must be instances of CommsMessage
# both of the following would operate the same way
CommsQueue: TypeAlias = queue.Queue[CommsMessage]
CommsQueue: TypeAlias = queue.Queue[CommsMsg]
# also useful for annotating aliases that use forward references
# allowing type checker to distinguish from var assignment to str
CommsQueue: TypeAlias = "queue.Queue[CommsMessage]"

# initialize a queue type hinted as CommsQueue
comms_rx_q: CommsQueue = queue.Queue()
```

I also use pycharm and the following works for me:

```
import queue
from typing import TypeAlias, NewType


class CommsMessage:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    @staticmethod
    def test():
        print("testing")


msg1 = CommsMessage("message1")
msg2 = CommsMessage("message2")
msg3 = CommsMessage("message3")
messages = [msg1, msg2, msg3]

CommsQueue: TypeAlias = queue.Queue[CommsMessage]
CommsMsg = NewType('CommsMessage', CommsMessage)
comms_rx_q: CommsQueue = queue.Queue()

for msg in messages:
    comms_rx_q.put(msg)

while not comms_rx_q.empty():
    comms_rx = CommsMsg(comms_rx_q.get(block=True, timeout=0.1))
    print(type(comms_rx))
    # <class '__main__.CommsMessage'>
    print(comms_rx.message)
    comms_rx.test()

print(CommsQueue)
# queue.Queue[__main__.CommsMessage]
print(type(CommsQueue))
# <class 'types.GenericAlias'>
```

PS: TypeAlias is available from python version 3.10 so you'd need to be working in at least that version. If you cannot upgrade, though, doing this should suffice:

```
# assign your type signature to an alias
CommsQueue = queue.Queue[CommsMessage]
```

Further, if you did not want to use NewType to CommsMsg as a subtype, which may or may not be relevant to you, or prefer not to import the typing module, doing this should also suffice:

```
comms_rx: CommsMessage = comms_rx_q.get(block=True, timeout=0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  Rather than needing to test the instance type, I'm trying to hint to PyCharm that comms_rx is an instance of CommsMessage so that code checking and autocompletion works correctly.  Maybe I've asked the wrong question.  I've assumed that to get the PyCharm behaviour I want I must explicitly cast comms_rx, but perhaps that's not what I need to do.

Comment: hopefully my edit helps

Comment: Thanks @harriet.  I tried your last suggestion and it works fine.  Best regards...Paul